# exit and back button implementation

Tags: android, button, widget, exit, back-button

Either exit button or back button only can be implemented in my application.But i want both the implementations in my application. So,Please propose me a solution.

Thanks in Advance..:)

Comment: What are you talking about. What do you want them to be implemented to do?

Answer (score 2):

Please read Reto Meier's blogpost on 'exit' in Android apps:

http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html

Summary: Don't put an 'exit button' in an Android app.

Comment: Google includes an exit button in their sample project. Not sure what Reto used as a basis for his blogpost.

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead:

```
syste.exit(0);
```

Comment: You should not use System.exit, just call finish().